# What are good ways of passing an array or hash in client side javascript to server side ruby?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Main criteria is ease of manipulation and portability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON would be my choice, easy to generate in javascript and just as easy to parse directly into a hash in Ruby.

Ruby (irb session):

```
>> require 'json'
=> true
>> {:name => 'Chris Cherry', :emails => ['test1@test.com', 'test2@test.com']}.to_json
=> "{"emails":["test1@test.com","test2@test.com"],"name":"Chris Cherry"}"
>> json_string = _
=> "{"emails":["test1@test.com","test2@test.com"],"name":"Chris Cherry"}"
>> JSON.parse(json_string)
=> {"name"=>"Chris Cherry", "emails"=>["test1@test.com", "test2@test.com"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using rails, you can take advantage of the fact that ActiveSupport has JSON support.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > j = ActiveSupport::JSON
 => ActiveSupport::JSON 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004 > j.encode({:team => "Celtics", :players => "20"})
 => "{\"team\":\"Celtics\",\"players\":\"20\"}" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005 > j.decode("{\"team\":\"Celtics\",\"players\":\"20\"}")
 => {"team"=>"Celtics", "players"=>"20"}
```